# Background image won't load Html/css

Tags: html, css

Hello I want to put a background image to my html page unfortunately it does not want to be displayed even though I specified the relative path of the image in url in the css how to do? I also have this error Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND I do not understand

My css path is also the right one, in fact it works when I load an image in html but when I want to load a background image in css it does not work.

```
body {
    background-image : url('images/nightvision.jpg'); 
}
```

see how folder are organized [image: exemple]

I want the image as the background

**EDIT : I think it's working with**

```
background-image : url('../images/nightvision.jpg');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you are using the right image extension? Like `.png`, `.jpeg`?

If that is clear, perhaps you could try to be more specific and add something like:

```
url('../images/nightvision.jpg');
```